# sequence of events in shiny r when simulating button clicks by javascript in a loop

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

I am simulating several clicks on an action button by doing javascript calls `document.getElementById('btn').click();` in a loop.
The issue is that the loop runs first to the end (say 3 times as in example below) and only after that the clicks on the button actually happen (3 in a row).
I want to change this behavior so that the loop with js code waits until the triggered observeEvent for the button stops executing and only then proceeds to the next `i` value.

The below code demonstrates this behavior by outputting sequence of events into textOutput.
Pressing "trigger" produces:

> TRIGGER,  TRIGGER,  TRIGGER,  BUTTON,  BUTTON,  BUTTON,

And what I want is

> TRIGGER,  BUTTON,  TRIGGER,  BUTTON,  TRIGGER,  BUTTON,

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    actionButton("trigger", "Trigger 3 clicks"),
    actionButton("btn", "BUTTON"),
    verbatimTextOutput("num"),
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    
    sequence <- reactiveVal(c())
    
    observeEvent(input$trigger, {
      for (i in 1:3) {
        sequence(append(sequence(), "TRIGGER, "))
        runjs("document.getElementById('btn').click();")
      }
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$btn, {
      sequence(append(sequence(), "BUTTON, "))
      output$num <- renderText(sequence())
    })
  }
)
```

Comment: I think it makes sense because the expression in `observeEvent(input$trigger` will be evaluated completely before any other calls are done. The bits in `runjs` will be added to the event loop but not executed immediately at all. Typically not a good idea to write code in shiny that assumes an order of execution, better to use reactives / observeEvents to ensure a logical order of operation.